# Assign section and row indexpath to prepareForSeague

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to get the `indexpath.section` and `indexpath.row` for my `prepareForSeague`. I can pass the `indexpath.row` no problem however I am struggling to integrate it with sections. It passes the correct data across but not when outside the first section as I do not know how to set the sections.

So basically I need it to know which section it is in too.

I looked at `objectsAtIndexes`?

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
dynamicDetailTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
NSLog(@" indexPath row %d",indexPath.row);
NSLog(@" indexPath section %d",indexPath.section);

// Assume self.view is the table view
destViewController.titleString = [self.namesArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
//Health
destViewController.healthArray = [self.healthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**EDIT**

To make it clearer, it does work however I have different sections so after the first section it doesn't pass the right value. It passes only the first Sections values correct as it is only calculating the indexpath based on the row and not the section. I need it to calculate the section too, but not sure how.

Comment: It seems fine, doesn't the `NSLog` output the expected value, or what is the problem?

Comment: What do you see in the logs when you print the row and section?

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear. It does work howwever I have different sections so after the first section it doesn't pass the right value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your data structure is wrong, if you have multiple sections and rows. Your data structure should look something like below

**Section 1**

----> Row 1

----> Row 2

----> Row 3

**Section 2**

----> Row 1

----> Row 2

**Section 3**

----> Row 1

----> Row 2

----> Row 3

----> Row 4

And to fetch the values your code should be something like

```
[[self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

The above code says give me particular `row` for the particular `section`.

In your case it doesn't seems to be the case, you have got all the data in a single array, where as it should be array of array.

You are getting wrong values because for each indexPath.section your indexPath.row starts with 0, so for 1st section it works fine, but not for other sections..

Hope it helps.